# Odd bit of syntax that Java allows in for loops, using a comma to separate iterations.

Tags: java, syntax

This bit of code works fine:

```
for(int i=0, j=10; j<20; i++, j++)
{
    System.out.println("i = " + i + ", and j= " + j);
}
```

Is there another place where a comma separating incrementation is allowed?  Why isn't a semicolon separation?

Comment: If a semicolon is used for separation, how will you separate the 3 arguments of a `for` loop? And no, you've got them all. Assignment and increment can work with multiple variables.

Comment: This is allowed the same way as when declaring variables: `int x = 5, y = 20;`

Answer (score 0):

[Java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html) - **15.27.** Expression

```
Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language has no comma operator.
```

So it's only really allowed to chain assignments.

Comment: I found it odd because I can't do:

`int x;`

`int y;`

`x++, y++;`

Comment: They're unassigned there, but it still won't allow that because that's an expression (not assignment). It does allow `int x = 1, y = 2;`